# What files do I need to make a docker image for running Zombienet tests?

Tags: parachain, docker, zombienet, substrate-parachain-template

I have built my parachain release.

Here are the files/folders I have inside my target/release:

```
11G .
5.9G    ./deps
3.2G    ./wbuild
1.6G    ./build
134M    ./parachain-collator
49M     ./.fingerprint
30M     ./libp_chain_runtime.rlib
784K    ./libpallet_erc721.rlib
760K    ./libpallet_crowdloan_rewards.rlib
540K    ./parachain-collator.d
540K    ./libp_chain_runtime.d
240K    ./libpallet_template.rlib
4.0K    ./libpallet_template.d
4.0K    ./libpallet_erc721.d
4.0K    ./libpallet_crowdloan_rewards.d
4.0K    ./incremental
4.0K    ./examples
0   ./.cargo-lock
```

You can see the total size target/release is 11GB, which is quite large.

Now I need to wrap them into a docker image as part of a CI/CD testing process.

Which files/folders do I need to copy into my docker image so my docker parachain image can perform some simple Zombienet tests below?

- check the parachain is registered within certain time
- check the parachain can produce blocks(block height is x within certain time)

Specifically, do I really need deps, wbuild, and build folders?

Do I also need CACHEDIR.TAG, and debug folder under project/target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to add copy the `parachain-collator` binary to the image to use in `CI`. You can check the [collator_injected.Dockerfile](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/scripts/ci/dockerfiles/collator_injected.Dockerfile) from the polkadot repo.